# Compute limit which includes $o$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{(x-1)^2+o((x-1)^2)}{(x-1)^4+o((x-1)^4)}$$
I really do not understand how to deal with the $o$ in order to compute the limit. My guess to this question is that the answer should be $\infty$. Please help me!

Comment: I would suggest factoring out:

$$
\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\frac{1 + \frac{o(x-1)^2)}{(x-1)^2}}{1 + \frac{o((x-1)^4)}{(x-1)^4}}
$$

You should be able to then change the variables to be a limit to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have asymptotic notation, you need to have a limit that goes towards infinity.  This is not immediately obvious how to do but since you clearly have a variable going towards $0$ it should be easy to convert it to a limit going to infinity.  First, clearly you could restate your problem as:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2 + o(x^2)}{x^4 + o(x^4)}
$$

Now we can restate it further as:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2}} + o\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^4}} + o\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^4}}\right)}
$$

Now we can call $\frac{1}{x^2} = X$ and restate as:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}
$$

At this point, we choose some functions $f \in o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ and $g\in o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}\frac{1 + \frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}}{1 + \frac{g(x)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x\frac{1 + \frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}}{1 + \frac{g(x)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}}
$$

We *know* that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}} = 0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{g(x)}{\frac{1}{x^2}} = 0$ ([by definition of little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)).

Using the multiplication rule, this gives:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x\frac{1 + \frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}}{1 + \frac{g(x)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}} = \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x\right)\cdot \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1 + \frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}}{1 + \frac{g(x)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}}\right) = \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\right)\cdot 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely rigorous as you really need both limits to exist as real numbers to use $\lim f(x)g(x) = \lim f(x)\lim g(x)$, but the idea is:

$$\require{cancel}\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{(x-1)^2+ o((x-1)^2)}{(x-1)^4+o((x-1)^4)} = \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^4}\frac{1+\cancel{\frac{o((x-1)^2)}{(x-1)^2}}}{1+\cancel{\frac{o((x-1)^4)}{(x-1)^4}}} = \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^4} = \infty$$

If you're a bit more careful you could turn this into a rigorous argument, though.

Comment: Thank you! But I have a question about how you can cancel out the 2 terms that you canceled. Is that because that they are equal to 0?

Comment: @Godpandali: By definition of small $o$ notation the limit of these two terms is $0$.

Comment: Why is it that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{o\left((x-1)^2\right)}{(x-1)^2} = 0$???

Comment: @Jared That's basically the definition of $o((x-1)^2)$.  A function $f$ is $o(g)$ as $x\to c$ if $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.  The question doesn't say that $c$ is $1$ in this case, but I think that's a fairly reasonable assumption.

Comment: @Bye_World The reason I asked my question is that that's _not_ the definition of little-o notation. For example $f(x) = (x - 1) \in o\left((x - 1)^2\right)$ but obviously $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x- 1}{(x - 1)^2} \neq 0$. On the _other_ hand, the proper definition holds: $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x - 1}{(x - 1)^2} = 0$.